# setColorFilter to imageView

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I implemented onTouchListener for an imageView that puts a opacity filter on it when touched

```
ima.setOnTouchListener(new TextView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
                    ima.setColorFilter(0x80FFFFFF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
                    ima.clearColorFilter();
                    v.performClick();
                } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL == event.getAction()) {
                    ima.clearColorFilter();                      
                }
                else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL == event.getAction()) {
                    ima.clearColorFilter();                       
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

When I scroll on the layout an press the image by mistake it put the filter for a sudden.
I need to put this filter only when i really want to press this image. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Define "really want to press". If you succeed in that, you have your answer.

Comment: to keep pressing the imageview for a while. eg 0.2s

Comment: You can use `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)` for that. Apply the color filter in the runnable, and cancel it when necessary when the 0.2s haven't passed yet.

Comment: If I use handler i need to interrupt it in case I scrool before 0.2 have passed. Is that right? Otherwise the imageview will remain painted forever